# Передача char* по ссылке в функцию

Tags: c, указатели, память

Да, вопрос немного "глупый", однако..

Есть функция вида:

```
bool F(char* b)
{
    b = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    return true;
}
```

И вот вызываю функцию:

```
char* buf = NULL;
F(b);
```

По выходу из функции `b` остается равен `NULL`. Подскажите, как верно передать указатель, чтобы он вернулся с памятью (и адресом)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, раз это C, вариант передачи по ссылке не годится - так что передавайте адрес:

```
bool F(char** b)
{
    *b = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    return true;
}

char* buf = NULL;
F(&b);
```

Comment: благодарю, все заработало!

Answer (score 1):

А можно реализовать немного по-другому (этот метод мне даже кажется более элегантным):

```
char * F (void)
{
    return malloc (100 * sizeof (char));
}
```

Таким образом ф-цей можно пользоваться как `malloc`

```
char *buf = F();
```

Можно даже объявить не как ф-цию, а как макрос.

Comment: Функция уже возвращает значение, это я минимальный пример просто привёл :)